# how to evaluate the performance of any cryptographic algorithm (say elliptic curve)?

Tags: c#, security, cryptography

I'm working on PHD which entitled "secure localization for wireless sensor networks". I built my own .net simulator and built a localization algorithm over it and make this algorithm secure by implementing an Elliptic Curve Cryptography algorithm. Final step, I need to evaluate the performance of this security algorithm. Can any one help me? thanks in advance.
This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using networkdll;
using Mapack;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

 namespace Kalman_Filter_Secure
 {
 public class Kalman_Filter_Secure
  {

    public Label enc_label;
    public Label dec_label;
    public TimeSpan counter1;
    public int counter, slot_duration, delimiter = 0, collision_percent;
    public DateTime timeStart;
    public String path;
    public float locatorRadius = 0, sensorRadius = 0, BSSRadius = 0;
    public object sender = null;
    public PaintEventArgs e = null;
    public ArrayList asensor = new ArrayList();
    public ArrayList alocator = new ArrayList();
    public ArrayList amlocator = new ArrayList();
    public ArrayList aBase_Stations = new ArrayList();
    public bool mobanchor = false;
    //public Random rand = new Random((int)System.DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    public Kalman_Filter_Secure(object sender, PaintEventArgs e, ArrayList asensor, ArrayList alocator, ArrayList amlocator, TimeSpan counter1, int slot_duration, String path, float locatorRadius, float sensorRadius, bool mobanchor, int delimiter, int collision_percent, float BSSRadius, ArrayList aBase_Stations, double q,/*double pd,*/ double r_x, double r_y, double r_vx, double r_vy, double ax_noise, double ay_noise, Label encrypt_label, Label decrypt_label)
    {
        set_parameters(locatorRadius, sensorRadius, counter1, slot_duration, mobanchor, collision_percent, BSSRadius, encrypt_label, decrypt_label);
        connectm(asensor, amlocator, aBase_Stations);

        Encrypt_Send(asensor);
        Receive_Decrypt(asensor);

        localize(sender, e, asensor, locatorRadius, path, delimiter, q, r_x, r_y, r_vx, r_vy, ax_noise, ay_noise);
    }

    public void set_parameters(float locatorRadius, float sensorRadius, TimeSpan counter1, int slot_duration, bool mobanchor, int collision_percent, float BSSRadius, Label encrypt_label, Label decrypt_label)
    {
        this.enc_label = encrypt_label;
        this.dec_label = decrypt_label;
        this.locatorRadius = locatorRadius;
        this.sensorRadius = sensorRadius;
        this.BSSRadius = BSSRadius;
        this.counter1 = counter1;
        this.slot_duration = slot_duration;
        this.mobanchor = mobanchor;
        this.collision_percent = collision_percent;
    }


    public void connectm(ArrayList asensor, ArrayList amlocator, ArrayList aBase_Stations)
    {
        int sensor_slot = 0, anchor_slot = 0;
        //TDMA protocol for collision free

        for (int j = amlocator.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)//anchors slots
        {

            networkdll.Class1.Locator jLocator = (networkdll.Class1.Locator)amlocator[j];

            jLocator.Slot = new ArrayList();
            //Base Station Connection
            for (int i = 0; i < aBase_Stations.Count; i++)
            {
                networkdll.Class1.Base_Station BSS = (networkdll.Class1.Base_Station)aBase_Stations[i];
                float BSS_lRadius = (float)(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(BSS.x - jLocator.x, 2) + Math.Pow(BSS.y - jLocator.y, 2)));//BSS-locator distance
                if (BSS_lRadius <= BSSRadius)
                {
                    jLocator.Slot.Add((new networkdll.Class1.Slot(counter1.Milliseconds)));       //BSS sensor connection
                }
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0);
        }

        for (int j = asensor.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)//sensors slots
        {

            networkdll.Class1.WirelessSensor jSensor = (networkdll.Class1.WirelessSensor)asensor[j];

            jSensor.Slot = new ArrayList();

            //Base Station Connection
            for (int i = 0; i < aBase_Stations.Count; i++)
            {
                networkdll.Class1.Base_Station BSS = (networkdll.Class1.Base_Station)aBase_Stations[i];
                float BSS_sRadius = (float)(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(BSS.x - jSensor.x, 2) + Math.Pow(BSS.y - jSensor.y, 2)));//BSS-sensor distance
                if (BSS_sRadius <= BSSRadius)
                {
                    jSensor.Slot.Add((new networkdll.Class1.Slot(counter1.Milliseconds)));       //BSS sensor connection
                }
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < asensor.Count; j++)
        {

            networkdll.Class1.WirelessSensor jSensor = (networkdll.Class1.WirelessSensor)asensor[j];
            jSensor.apkts = new ArrayList();//anchors packets
            jSensor.enc_apkts = new ArrayList();//encrypted anchors packets
            jSensor.Connections = new ArrayList();//anchors connection

            jSensor.spkts = new ArrayList();//neighbors packets
            jSensor.enc_spkts = new ArrayList();//encrypted neighbors packets
            jSensor.sConnection = new ArrayList();//neighbors connection

            jSensor.two_hop_apkts = new ArrayList();//two hop anchors packets
            jSensor.enc_two_hop_apkts = new ArrayList();//encrypted two hop anchors packets
            jSensor.two_hop_Connections = new ArrayList();//two hop anchors connection

            for (int i = 0; i < amlocator.Count; i++)
            {

                networkdll.Class1.Locator iLocator = (networkdll.Class1.Locator)amlocator[i];
                float lsRadius = (float)(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(iLocator.x - jSensor.x, 2) + Math.Pow(iLocator.y - jSensor.y, 2)));

                //get the associated slot for this anchor
                foreach (networkdll.Class1.Slot Slot in iLocator.Slot)
                    anchor_slot = Slot.slot;

                if (lsRadius <= locatorRadius && counter1.Milliseconds == anchor_slot)
                {
                    jSensor.Connections.Add(new networkdll.Class1.WirelessSensorConnection(iLocator, jSensor));       //MCL-MP

                    for (int k = i + 1; k < amlocator.Count; k++)//2-hop anchor connections
                    {
                        networkdll.Class1.Locator kLocator = (networkdll.Class1.Locator)amlocator[k];
                        float llRadius = (float)(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(iLocator.x - kLocator.x, 2) + Math.Pow(iLocator.y - kLocator.y, 2)));//anchor-anchor distance
                        float slRadius = (float)(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(kLocator.x - jSensor.x, 2) + Math.Pow(kLocator.y - jSensor.y, 2)));//2-hop anchor-sensor distance

                        //get the associated slot for this anchor
                        foreach (networkdll.Class1.Slot Slot in kLocator.Slot)
                            anchor_slot = Slot.slot;

                        if (llRadius <= locatorRadius && llRadius != 0 && slRadius > locatorRadius && counter1.Milliseconds == anchor_slot)
                        {
                            jSensor.two_hop_Connections.Add(new networkdll.Class1.WirelessSensorConnection(kLocator, jSensor));       //2-hop anchors connection
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            for (int k = j + 1; k < asensor.Count; k++)
            {

                networkdll.Class1.WirelessSensor kSensor = (networkdll.Class1.WirelessSensor)asensor[k];
                float ssRadius = (float)(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(kSensor.x - jSensor.x, 2) + Math.Pow(kSensor.y - jSensor.y, 2)));

                //get the associated slot for this anchor
                foreach (networkdll.Class1.Slot Slot in kSensor.Slot)
                    sensor_slot = Slot.slot;

                if (ssRadius <= sensorRadius && counter1.Milliseconds == sensor_slot)
                {
                    jSensor.sConnection.Add(new networkdll.Class1.WirelessSensorConnection(kSensor, jSensor));       //sensor-sensor connection 

                    //2-hop anchor connection via 1-hop sensor
                    for (int a = 0; a < alocator.Count; a++)
                    {
                        networkdll.Class1.Locator kLocator = (networkdll.Class1.Locator)amlocator[a];
                        float lsRadius = (float)(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(kSensor.x - kLocator.x, 2) + Math.Pow(kSensor.y - kLocator.y, 2)));//2-hop anchor-sensor"neighbor" distance
                        float slRadius = (float)(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(kLocator.x - jSensor.x, 2) + Math.Pow(kLocator.y - jSensor.y, 2)));//2-hop anchor-sensor distance

                        //get the associated slot for this anchor
                        foreach (networkdll.Class1.Slot Slot in kLocator.Slot)
                            anchor_slot = Slot.slot;

                        if (lsRadius <= locatorRadius && lsRadius != 0 && slRadius > locatorRadius && counter1.Milliseconds == anchor_slot)
                        {
                            jSensor.two_hop_Connections.Add(new networkdll.Class1.WirelessSensorConnection(kLocator, jSensor));       //2-hop anchors connection
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
   public static class Elliptic_Curve_Cryptography
    {
        private static Aes DeriveKeyAndIv(ECDiffieHellmanCng privateKey, ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey publicKey)
        {
            privateKey.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;
            privateKey.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
            byte[] keyAndIv = privateKey.DeriveKeyMaterial(publicKey);//derive secret key and initialization vector
            byte[] key = new byte[16];
            Array.Copy(keyAndIv, 0, key, 0, 16);
            byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            Array.Copy(keyAndIv, 16, iv, 0, 16);

            Aes aes = new AesManaged();
            aes.Key = key;  //secret (session) key
            aes.IV = iv;    //initialization vector
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            return aes;
        }

        public static byte[] Encrypt(ECDiffieHellmanCng privateKey, ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey publicKey, byte[] data)
        {
            Aes aes = DeriveKeyAndIv(privateKey, publicKey);
            return aes.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        public static byte[] Decrypt(ECDiffieHellmanCng privateKey, ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey publicKey, byte[] encryptedData)
        {
            Aes aes = DeriveKeyAndIv(privateKey, publicKey);
            return aes.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
        }
    }

    public void Encrypt_Send(ArrayList asensor)
    {
        ECDiffieHellmanCng Anchor_key = new ECDiffieHellmanCng();//Anchor private key
        String plain = "";
        String enc = "Encrypted\n";
        foreach (networkdll.Class1.WirelessSensor sensor in asensor)
        {
            ECDiffieHellmanCng Sensor_key = new ECDiffieHellmanCng();//Sensor private key

            foreach (networkdll.Class1.WirelessSensorConnection connection in sensor.Connections)//sensor - 1_hop anchor
            {
                plain = connection.sLocator.id + "," + connection.sLocator.x + ";" + connection.sLocator.y + ".";
                byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plain);//plain text
                byte[] encryptedData = Elliptic_Curve_Cryptography.Encrypt(Anchor_key, Sensor_key.PublicKey, data);//ECC cipher text
                String encrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encryptedData);//encrypted string
                sensor.enc_apkts.Add(new networkdll.Class1.enc_pkt(encryptedData, Anchor_key.PublicKey, Sensor_key));
                enc += encrypted + "\n";
            }
        }
            enc_label.Text = enc;

    }

    public void Receive_Decrypt(ArrayList asensor)
    {
        String dec = "Decrypted\n";
        foreach (networkdll.Class1.WirelessSensor sensor in asensor)
        {

            foreach (networkdll.Class1.enc_pkt packet in sensor.enc_apkts)//sensor - 1-hop anchor
            {
                byte[] decryptedData = Elliptic_Curve_Cryptography.Decrypt(packet.sensor_private_key, packet.anchor_public_key, packet.Encrypted);
                String decrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedData);
                sensor.apkts.Add(new networkdll.Class1.pkt(int.Parse(decrypted.Substring(0, decrypted.IndexOf(","))), int.Parse(decrypted.Substring(decrypted.IndexOf(",") + 1, decrypted.IndexOf(";") - decrypted.IndexOf(",") - 1)), int.Parse(decrypted.Substring(decrypted.IndexOf(";") + 1, decrypted.IndexOf(".") - decrypted.IndexOf(";") - 1))));
                dec += decrypted.Substring(0, decrypted.IndexOf(",")) + " (" + decrypted.Substring(decrypted.IndexOf(",") + 1, decrypted.IndexOf(";") - decrypted.IndexOf(",") - 1) + "," + decrypted.Substring(decrypted.IndexOf(";") + 1, decrypted.IndexOf(".") - decrypted.IndexOf(";") - 1) + ")\n";
            }
        }

       dec_label.Text = dec;

    }


    public void localize(object sender, PaintEventArgs e, ArrayList asensor, float locatorRadius, String path, int delimiter, double q, double r_x, double r_y, double r_vx, double r_vy, double ax_noise, double ay_noise)
    {

        Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", 7.0f);
        StringFormat format = new StringFormat();
        format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;


        Brush abrush = Brushes.PowderBlue;  //Actual anchor position
        Brush cbrush = Brushes.Purple;  //corrected position
        //Pen p = Pens.Violet;
        // Pen p1 = Pens.Black;
        String time = "";
        long start, end, executiontime;
        start = System.DateTime.Now.Ticks;


        int s = 0, count = 0; //sensor index,count for average error
        int ersum, avger = 0;//error summation
        int comm_cost = 0;//communication cost = no. of packets generated
        float coverage = 0; //no. of localized sensor nodes

        String ext = "", del = "";//file extension and column delimiter type "comma or tab" 
        String result = "";
        String result1 = "";//cumulate all results for all slot 

        if (delimiter == 0)
        {
            del = ","; ext = "xls";
            result = "Node" + del + "EstX" + del + "EstY" + del + "ActualX" + del + "ActualY" + del + "Error" + del + "1hAnchor\n";
        }
        else if (delimiter == 1)
        {
            del = "\t"; ext = "doc";
            result = "Node" + del + "EstX" + del + "EstY" + del + "ActualX" + del + "ActualY" + del + "Error" + del + "1hAnchor\n";
            result += "========================================================================\n";
        }
        float estx = 0, esty = 0;

        if (counter1.Minutes == 0)
            counter = counter1.Seconds;
        else counter = counter1.Seconds + counter1.Minutes * 60;

        if (counter % slot_duration == 0)
        {
            ersum = 0; avger = 0;


            s = 0;
            foreach (networkdll.Class1.WirelessSensor sensor in asensor)
            {
                int ax = 0, ay = 0;
                /* System.Random rs = new System.Random();//so as to change the random value with every slot
                long seed = rs.Next();
                Random r = new Random(seed, true);*/

                Kalman k = new Kalman();
                Random r = new Random();

                //measured velocity
                double mvx = 0;         //sensor.speed * Math.Cos((360 - sensor.direction) * Math.PI / 180.0);
                double mvy = 0;         //sensor.speed * Math.Sin((360 - sensor.direction) * Math.PI / 180.0);
                double velocity = 0, theta = 0;

                if ((counter / slot_duration) >= 2)
                {
                    String loca1 = path + "\\state(" + ((counter / slot_duration) - 2) + ")_Sensor(" + s + ")" + ".xls";
                    String loca2 = path + "\\state(" + ((counter / slot_duration) - 1) + ")_Sensor(" + s + ")" + ".xls";

                    Matrix predc1 = new Matrix(4, 1);
                    Matrix predc2 = new Matrix(4, 1);

                    try
                    {
                        //read previous state m_x
                        using (StreamReader re = new StreamReader(loca1))
                        {

                            for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
                            {
                                string line = re.ReadLine();
                                string[] values = line.Split(',');

                                for (int col = 0; col < 1; col++)
                                {
                                    predc1[row, col] = double.Parse(values[col]);
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        using (StreamReader re = new StreamReader(loca2))
                        {

                            for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
                            {
                                string line = re.ReadLine();
                                string[] values = line.Split(',');

                                for (int col = 0; col < 1; col++)
                                {
                                    predc2[row, col] = double.Parse(values[col]);
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        double predc1x = predc1[0, 0];
                        double predc1y = predc1[1, 0];
                        double predc2x = predc2[0, 0];
                        double predc2y = predc2[1, 0];

                        //measured direction
                        if (predc1x == predc2x && predc2y > predc1y)
                            theta = 270;
                        else if (predc1x == predc2x && predc2y < predc1y)
                            theta = 90;
                        else if (predc1y == predc2y && predc2x < predc1x)
                            theta = 180;
                        else if (predc1y == predc2y && predc2x > predc1x)
                            theta = 0;
                        else
                            theta = Math.Atan((predc2y - predc1y) / (predc1x - predc2x)) * (180 * 7 / 22);
                        if (theta < 0)
                            theta = -theta;

                        //measured velocity
                        velocity = (double)(Math.Sqrt(((predc2y - predc1y) * (predc2y - predc1y) + (predc1x - predc2x) * (predc1x - predc2x)))) / (double)slot_duration;

                    }
                    catch { velocity = 0; }

                }
                //measured speed in x and y directions (x',y')
                mvx = velocity * Math.Cos((360 - theta) * Math.PI / 180.0);
                mvy = velocity * Math.Sin((360 - theta) * Math.PI / 180.0);

                ////////////////1-hop anchor measurement/////////////////
                foreach (networkdll.Class1.pkt packet1 in sensor.apkts)    //1-hop anchor packet
                {
                    ax += packet1.x;
                    ay += packet1.y;
                }

                /////////////////Slot 0: Reset Kalman Filter////////////////////////////
                if (counter / slot_duration == 0)
                {
                    k.Reset(s, path, q, slot_duration, r_x, r_y, r_vx, r_vy, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                }

                /////////Prediction and Correction Phases/////////////////

                if (sensor.apkts.Count >= 1)
                {

                    Matrix state = k.Update(s, path, (counter / slot_duration), (ax / sensor.apkts.Count) + r.NextGuass_Double(0, ax_noise), (ay / sensor.apkts.Count) + r.NextGuass_Double(0, ay_noise), mvx, mvy, slot_duration);         //*, px_noise, py_noise*/

                    float erx, ery;//error (x,y)
                    estx = (float)state[0, 0];
                    esty = (float)state[1, 0];
                    erx = Math.Abs(estx - sensor.x);
                    ery = Math.Abs(esty - sensor.y);

                    result += s + del + estx + del + esty + del + sensor.x + del + sensor.y + del + (int)Math.Sqrt(erx * erx + ery * ery) + del + sensor.apkts.Count + "\n";
                    ersum += (int)Math.Sqrt(erx * erx + ery * ery);//sum error
                    comm_cost += sensor.apkts.Count;//communication cost
                    count++;

                    g.FillEllipse(abrush, ((float)ax / (float)sensor.apkts.Count) - 5, ((float)ay / (float)sensor.apkts.Count) - 5, 10, 10);
                    g.FillEllipse(cbrush, estx - 5, esty - 5, 10, 10);
                    g.DrawString("(" + ((int)Math.Sqrt(erx * erx + ery * ery) / sensorRadius).ToString() + ")", font, Brushes.Black, estx + 6, esty + 6);

                    //writing actual measurements without noise
                    if (counter / slot_duration == 0)
                        //Creat file to store actual measurements all slots in one file
                        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path + "\\Actual_Measurement_Sensor(" + s + ")" + ".xls", FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
                            {
                                w.WriteLine("slot_No,AM_X,AM_Y");
                                w.WriteLine(counter / slot_duration + "," + (ax / sensor.apkts.Count) + "," + (ay / sensor.apkts.Count));
                            }
                        }
                    else
                        //Append to file that contains actual measurements
                        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path + "\\Actual_Measurement_Sensor(" + s + ")" + ".xls", FileMode.Append))
                        {
                            using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
                            {
                                w.WriteLine(counter / slot_duration + "," + (ax / sensor.apkts.Count) + "," + (ay / sensor.apkts.Count));
                            }
                        }


                }


                /////storing actual sensor data
                double avx = sensor.speed * Math.Cos((360 - sensor.direction) * Math.PI / 180.0);
                double avy = sensor.speed * Math.Sin((360 - sensor.direction) * Math.PI / 180.0);

                //storing Actual position and velocity of sensor node
                if ((counter / slot_duration) == 0)
                    //Create file to store actual state of sensor
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path + "\\Actual_Sensor(" + s + ")" + ".xls", FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
                        {
                            w.WriteLine("slot_No,Actual_X,Actual_Y,Actual_X',Actual_Y'");
                            w.WriteLine((counter / slot_duration) + "," + sensor.x + "," + sensor.y + "," + avx + "," + avy);
                        }
                    }
                else
                    //Append to file that contains  actual state of sensor
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path + "\\Actual_Sensor(" + s + ")" + ".xls", FileMode.Append))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
                        {
                            w.WriteLine((counter / slot_duration) + "," + sensor.x + "," + sensor.y + "," + avx + "," + avy);
                        }
                    }
                s++;
            }



            end = System.DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            executiontime = end - start;
            time = " " + (double)(executiontime / 10000);

            if (count != 0) { avger = ersum / count; }
            if (s != 0 && count != 0) coverage = (float)((float)count / (float)s) * 100;

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path + "\\Kalman_of_slot" + (counter / slot_duration) + "." + ext, FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    w.WriteLine(result + "\n\n" + "\nAverage" + del + "error = " + del + avger + del + "m" + "\nPercent" + del + " error = " + del + (avger / sensorRadius) + del + "R" + "\nCommunication" + del + "cost = " + del + comm_cost + del + "packet\n" + /*"Computation" + del + "cost =" + del + time + del + "ms\n"*/ "Localized" + del + "sensors =" + del + coverage + del + "%");

                    w.Dispose();    //allows reading file while simulator opened
                }
            }
            //write all results for all slots
            if (delimiter == 1)
                result1 += (((counter)) / slot_duration) + del + (avger / sensorRadius) + del + del + del + comm_cost + del + del + /*time*/  del + coverage;
            else
                result1 += (((counter)) / slot_duration) + del + (avger / sensorRadius) + del + comm_cost + del + /*time*/ coverage;

            if (counter == 0)
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path + "\\Kalman_total_results." + ext, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        if (delimiter == 1)
                            w.WriteLine("Slot" + del + "Localization" + del + "Communication" + del + /*"Computation"*/  "Localized\nNo." + del + "Error \"R\"" + del + del + "Cost \"packet\"" + del + /*"Cost \"ms\""*/ "Sensors \"%\"\n===================================================================\n" + result1);

                        else
                            w.WriteLine("Slot" + del + "Localization" + del + "Communication" + del + /*"Computation"*/"Localized\nNo." + del + "Error \"R\"" + del + "Cost \"packet\"" + del + /*"Cost \"ms\""*/ "Sensors \"%\"\n" + result1);

                        w.Dispose();    //allows reading file while simulator opened
                    }
                }
            else
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path + "\\Kalman_total_results." + ext, FileMode.Append))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        w.WriteLine(result1);

                        w.Dispose();    //allows reading file while simulator opened
                    }
                }

        }


        // label.Text = output;
        //  label.Refresh();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you put some code please?

Comment: `I need to evaluate the performance of this security algorithm` - assuming you mean performance purely in terms of how fast it is rather than how difficult it is to break the encryption, then the question is still too vague - it depends on the size of the cipher keys, the implementation of the algorithm and the hardware it runs on. Or do you mean how much use of the cipher affects network bandwidth / latency? You need to learn how to ask questions better. And I'd love to be a fly on the wall at your thesis defence when you explain that someone on Stack Overflow gave you the answer.

Comment: (BTW the answer is that the performance sucks - but that's EDH for you)

Comment: I need to measure how fast and how difficult it is to break the encryption? irrespective of HW or cipher keys. thanks symcbean

Comment: So measure it. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551742/what-is-the-equivalent-to-system-nanotime-in-net) for a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use *eBATS: ECRYPT Benchmarking of Asymmetric Systems* from Dan Bernstein and Tanja Lange (http://bench.cr.yp.to/ebats.html). It is part of *eBACS: ECRYPT Benchmarking of Cryptographic Systems*.

"If you use eBACS information in a paper then you should cite the web pages as follows:
    Daniel J. Bernstein and Tanja Lange (editors). eBACS: ECRYPT Benchmarking of Cryptographic Systems. http://bench.cr.yp.to, accessed 7 March 2013.

Replace 7 March 2013 by your download date."